# Using two tables or one

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I currently working on a system which handles error logging, and currently 90% (some ~9 000 000 of ~10 000 000) of the log posts are diagnostics messages, which are barely used. The remaining are actual errors that need to be dealt with. The two types of logs contain mostly the same type of information, and are differntiated by a bit with a nonclustered index. I'm considering moving the diagnostics messages to a separate table, but I'm not sure it's Worth the effort.

Today the system isn't used extensively but it might change in the future, and I worry about the effects of the amount of diagnostics messages might have on performance. What pros/cons might I expect from creating a new table to handle the logging?

Answer (score 0):

Sql server (at least from 2008 r2 version) allows you to [create non-clustered filtered indexes.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372(v=sql.105).aspx)
So if you want to improve selecting just the rows where that bit column contains a specific value, you can use a filtered index on that column - keeping your index as small as possible and it's searches as effective as possible.

All you have to do is add a `where` clause to your index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX <IndexName>
ON <TableName> (<columnsList>)
WHERE <bitColumn> = 1 ;
```

Of course, you will need to replace everything inside the `<>` to actual names.

Comment: A bit column (with values 0 or 1) doesn't have low selectivity? If I remember correctly an index would help if there is a high selectivity (+70%). Filtered Indexes works in a different way?